# Соединение с обновлением в Entity Framework

Tags: c#, база-данных, .net, entity-framework, linq

Допустим имеется `List<Entity>` и сам context.Entity.

В `List<Entity>` могут содержаться записи, которые есть в Entity, в этом случае я должен обновить все свойства Entity.

В `List<Entity>` могут отсутствовать записи, которые есть в Entity, в этом случае свойству isDel присваивается 1.

В `List<Entity>` могут присутствовать записи, которые есть в Entity, в этом случае записи просто добавляются.

Как это красиво сделать в LINQ?

В классическом SQL, я бы сделал бы LEFT JOIN,INNER JOIN, RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: А обязательно пользовать LINQ? Почему бы не взять для этой задачи простой foreach?

Comment: А по скорости как будет?

Comment: На сколько я знаю, в разных случаях по разному. LINQ не всегда быстрее. В вашем случае, наверняка, вы не заметите разницы, какие нибудь жалкие милисекунды, если они и будут.

Comment: Вообще по сути LINQ должен быть даже медленнее, ибо он использует те же foreach или for циклы. Только ещё требуется время, что бы всё это перевести.

Comment: Но все равно было бы интересно посмотреть на решение через LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Есть красивое решение с использованием метода расширения `AddOrUpdate`. Но и в этом случае без `foreach` не обойтись.

```
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

List<Entity> list; // список должен быть инициализирован

var exceptList = context.Entity.Except(list);
foreach (var entity in exceptList)
{
    entity.isDel = true; // помечаем записи, которые отсутствуют в list
}

foreach (var entity in list)
{
    context.Entity.AddOrUpdate(entity); // обновляем существующую запись или добавляем новую
}
context.SaveChanges(); // сохраняем изменения
```

Comment: у меня такая ошибка вылетает на Except: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: Unable to create a constant value of type 'WCFConsoleServer.Models.Project'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.